# My garage door opener is hardwired so there is no outlet can I splice a new wire off that wire to create an Outlet

Tags: receptacle, splicing

So my one car garage has no outlets being I am in an apartment. I like to use my garage for woodworking projects all kinds of stuff not having an outlet sucks.
The garage door opener is hardwired in so there is no outlet. My question is can I splice  a new wire off of the existing one to give me at least one outlet

Comment: Where does the garage get the power from? If you tell me: the apartment breaker panel, then the answer is "no" because you can't work on a rental electrical. If you tell me "from a panel in or next to the garage", then the answer is to take a look at that panel first as there are a bunch of reasons why a new circuit would be better. That being said, if the garage door opener uses less than 1/2 the available power, yes it should be code legal and practical to add an ordinary receptacle. If you tell me "panel not accessible" then **NO** because unsafe to work on a circuit without shutting power.

Comment: Before modifying a rental's electrics, talk to the owner. They may not want you doing that, or may want you to get an electrician to do that. It's their property, remember, and their insurance that gets dinged if something goes wrong.

Comment: You're in an apartment. If that apartment is in the US (garage door opener is a strong hint it is), you cannot legally work on the electrics yourself.

Comment: (I’ll delete this comment if it turns out that you aren’t renting…) When you buy an extension cord, make it as short as possible and preferably 12awg.

Comment: Not only is is it illegal for anyone not a licensed electrician to work on the electrics in a Multiple Dwelling Unit in the US (even if you own it) it seems very likely (in part from the lack of any outlet there) that your garage is not on your power meter, so apart from the work being a violation, the outlet would also entail theft of electricity, if that is the case. Management may be happy to pay for operating the garage door opener they provide, but they will take a dim view of charging your Electric Vehicle or running your tablesaw from their meter.

Comment: You don't actually need power tools to do most woodworking; traditional hand tools take a bit more effort but they certainly can do the job.

Comment: Amazing that there is no receptacle in the wall of the garage! I would have thought this would be a code requirement. It says to me that the apartment management might not be accepting of power equipment being used in the garages. If you would rig a receptacle, management might object to woodworking activities being carried out in the garage.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Based on your description it is very likely that supply would be shared between multiple garages and was propably done for that specific purpouse.
As such would be rated for the garage doors only and relevantly fused.
Inductive loads often mean C graded fuses.

As you did not tell us anything about circuit breaker means that you can not consider supply characteristics. If it has no further switching then your actions can result in all the garage doors on a block to lose power...
Power tools use quite a loot of power especialy the DIY ones (designed to have more Wats often by reducing efficiency.

Although you did not state your country. In EU/UK you would have a safety swicth (fused spur) near the garage door which could tell you more.
On the other side in India it would propably be perfectly OK to tape the wires to the bulb.

Comment: The use of the word "apartment" instead of "flat" is a strong indicator that the OP is in the US (though not guaranteed, of course). We don't use fuses in the US except in _extremely_ old wiring. Also, that's a bit of a rude poke at India...

Comment: I guess its another language difference as in UK we often refer to other forms of circuit protection and even the consumer unit is often refered to as fusebox. In this case by fuse I have refered to any for of overcurent protection. While I may ocasionaly poke on india for badly written (researched) tutorials poluting googles first pages, This case wasn't a poke and in their sociaty and by the speciffic perception, the no nonsence approach is a valid option too. I like the idea of always finding a way...